# Validate inputs based on dropdown value being equal to a number

Tags: javascript, html

I have a select option:

```
<select name="state" id="state">
    <option value="none" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
    <option value="VIC">VIC</option>
    <option value="NSW">NSW</option>
    <option value="QLD">QLD</option>
    <option value="NT">NT</option>
    <option value="WA">WA</option>
    <option value="SA">SA</option>
    <option value="TAS">TAS</option> 
    <option value="ACT">ACT</option>  
</select>
```

And a textbox to enter a postcode:

```
<label for="postcode">Postcode: </label>
<input type="text" name="postcode" pattern="^[1-9]{4}$" id="postcode" size="4" required="required"/>
```

Basically we choose a state and in the next field I type in the postal code but a validation requirement needs me to do this:

> The selected state must match the first digit of the postcode VIC = 3
>   OR 8, NSW = 1 OR 2 ,QLD = 4 OR 9 ,NT = 0 ,WA = 6 ,SA=5 ,TAS=7 ,ACT= 0
>   (e.g. the postcode 3122 should match the state VIC)

I have implemented accessing both the values but I am not sure how to go about giving the state a number value (while retaining the normal value).

```
function validateEnquire() {
  var errMsg = "";
  var result = true; 

  var postcode=document.getElementById("postcode").value.trim();
  var state=document.getElementById("state").value.trim();

  //Implement state result

  if (!(postcode.charAt(0) == stateResult)) {
          errMsg = errMsg + "The postcode does not belong to the state\n"
          result = false;
  }

  if (errMsg != "") {
    alert(errMsg);
  }

  return result; 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have an object indexed by state, whose values are the permitted postcodes for that state:

```
const stateCodes = {
  VIC: ['3', '8'],
  NSW: ['1', '2'],
  QLD: ['4', '9'],
  // ...
};
// ...

  if (!stateCodes[stateResult].includes(postcode[0])) {
    // Error
  }
```

```js
const stateCodes = {
  VIC: ['3', '8'],
  NSW: ['1', '2'],
  QLD: ['4', '9'],
  // ...
};
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const selectedState = document.querySelector('#state').value;
  const postcode = document.querySelector('#postcode').value;
  if (!stateCodes[selectedState].includes(postcode[0])) {
    console.log("Code doesn't match state");
  } else {
    console.log('OK');
  }
});
```

```html
<form>
  <select name="state" id="state">
    <option value="none" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
    <option value="VIC">VIC</option>
    <option value="NSW">NSW</option>
    <option value="QLD">QLD</option>
    <option value="NT">NT</option>
    <option value="WA">WA</option>
    <option value="SA">SA</option>
    <option value="TAS">TAS</option>
    <option value="ACT">ACT</option>
  </select>
  <label for="postcode">Postcode: </label>
  <input type="text" name="postcode" pattern="^[1-9]{4}$" id="postcode" size="4" required="required" />
  <button>submit</button>
</form>
```

Note that you don't need to `.trim()` the value of the text if you already have the `^[1-9]{4}$` pattern, which requires no spaces.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you so much! I am completely unfamiliar with declaring a constant (stateCodes) like that. I will admit, I am not really sure how the if-statement is working. Sorry, I am completely new to Javascript.

Comment: `const` is ES2015 syntax, which everyone *should* be using by now. Best to [always use `const`](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/278652/how-much-should-i-be-using-let-vs-const-in-es6) when declaring variables - `var` has too many problems, and `let` permits reassignment, which is usually a bad idea.